# How to load Esper queries from config file?

Tags: esper

I am just getting started with Esper and used http://coffeeonesugar.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/getting-started-with-esper-in-5-minutes/
as a quick start reference. Could you point me to how to go about loading EPL queries via a config file instead of hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

Esper has a deployment admin API that can read EPL such as from a file. and deploy.